# MAMP attempting to connect to production SQL Database - localhost PHP Google App Engine Flexible Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine, mamp

I am hosting a WordPress site on Google App Engine Flexible Environment. I got my local server working with MAMP. Then I needed to add SSL to MAMP so that images on my site would appear in the local environment, and so I could update WordPress and Plugins using these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible. So I did that and (after hours) got it working.

Then, I stopped the MAMP servers to deploy the app to Google. When I tried restarting the servers, MySQL wouldn't load. After a TON of troubleshooting, trying to kill all SQL processes, I finally got MySQL to start by changing the port back to default (leaving the Apache port at 80 though).

[ports used on MAMP that finally worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uxgW.png)

Unfortunately, it took me back to the WordPress install when I did this. I again tried to get around it but finally thought "Ok let me just re-install WordPress." That didn't work and it gave an error message saying the database didn't have the WordPress tables. I created a new database through MAMP's PHPMyAdmin feature and tried again. It kept trying to pull from the old one which is when I realized (I think) that my if ($onGae) function stopped working for some reason and it was trying to pull from the production SQL database (Google's) instead of the local one.

I have no idea why this would stop working, it was working before. Maybe it has to do with Google's wp tool and my updating WordPress? Maybe I have the wrong SQL port? Let me know if there are any logs or other information I can provide. Thank you!

Also: I am not married to MAMP. I tried using the built-in PHP server (vendor/bin/wp --path=wordpress server) and it is also saying "Error establishing a database connection"

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working in MAMP. After continuing to try the built-in Google server and Wordpress's built-in server without luck, I created a new SQL database in MAMP's PHPMyAdmin and that fixed it. I had tried that yesterday and it didn't work but today a new database and updating my wp-config file to point to the new database worked.